# Validation in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was wandering why in books like `Agile Web Development with Rails` there's no mention to `validates_whatever_of` way of validating, all validation examples are done using `validates :attr, :whatever => true` ? I've just started learning Rails and this made me confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 2.x, where you would have said something like:

```
validates_presence_of :user_name
```

in 3.x, you now do:

```
validates :username, :presence => true
```

The old way is still supported, I think, but it is deprecated.

It's really just a different way of expressing the same thing. While older books and tutorials will use the former, it should be fairly simple to translate that to 3.x style. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `validates` syntax is just a [new shortcut](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) for the same thing. It's especially useful when you're validating a bunch of attributes with similar limits. So this:

```
validates_presence_of :one
validates_presence_of :two
validates_presence_of :three
validates_presence_of :four
```

can be reduced to

```
validates :one, :two, :three, :four, :presence => true
```

It's also a nice, consistent interface to custom validators.

Comment: but `validates_presence_of :one, :two, :three, :four` also works

Comment: Ah, I guess that's true. :-) It's probably contrived, but in the new scheme you can also validate other aspects using `validates` besides "presence" by tacking them onto `validates`. The best argument for the new scheme is that it's extensible without monkey patching ActiveRecord::Base. As in the example I liked to above, you can add a custom validator and it becomes available as option to `validates`. For example, creating an EmailValidator makes `:valid => true` available.

Comment: Err, I meant `:email => true`, but you get the idea.